# Splitting tokens into tokens using delimiters in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, token, delimiter

I have the following txt file that I need to split with tokens and save to an object:

> 1,Harry Potter,4,**3,11,14,20**
>
> 2,Matrix,3,**1,8,12**
>
> 3,Batman,3,**39,9,42**

Structure is: id, name, length, movieIds

Where length is reference to how many movieIds there are.

Not sure how to split movieIds separately or to set multiple values to the object as they override one another.

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(playlistLibrary);

        String str;
        String[] tokens;        

        for (int i = 1; i < playlist.length; i ++) {

            playlist[i] = new Playlist_17967352();

            if (inputFile.hasNext()) {

                str = inputFile.nextLine();
                tokens = str.split(","); 


                for (int a = 0; a < tokens.length; a ++) {

                    playlist[i].setId(tokens[0]);
                    playlist[i].setName(tokens[1]);
                    playlist[i].setLength(tokens[2]);

                    if (tokens.length > 3) {

                    int length = Integer.parseInt(playlist[i].getLength()); 

                            String movieIds;    

                        for (int b = 0, c = 3 ; b < length; b++, c++) {

                            movieIds = tokens[c];                                   
                            playlist[i].setMovies(movieIds);                                
                        }

                    }

                } // end for tokens.length  

                System.out.println(playlist[i].getMovies());
```

> Code output:
>
> 20
>
> 12
>
> 42

What I need is:

> 3,11,14,20
>
> 1,8,12
>
> 39,9,42

Comment: Is it within the realm of possibilities to update the file format? 1,Harry Potter,4,"3,11,14,20"

2,Matrix,3,"1,8,12"

3,Batman,3,"39,9,42"

Comment: Looks like CSV ([Comma-Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) data, so use a CSV parser, e.g. [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: @Andreas Yes, but his CSV format doesn't escape the movieIds so it won't work properly unless he adds the quotes

Comment: What is the signature for `setMovies()`?

Comment: @42shadow42 Storing `movieIds` in the Java structure as a comma-separated string is not the right answer (in my opinion). It should be a `List<Integer>` or `int[]`. As such, the values are truly separate values in the CSV text.

Comment: Unfortunately no I cannot update the file format.

Comment: I'm just using regular setters: public void setMovies(String movies) {
  playlistMovies = movies;
 }

Comment: I did try and save movieIds in an array however I need to set movieIds to an array of objects

Comment: What is the purpose of these movie ids? What do they represent? For example, what does the `3` in `1,Harry Potter,4,3,11,14,20` mean?

Comment: Each listing is a playlist that consists of other movieIds:
playlistId, playlistName, playlistLength, moviesInPlaylist

Comment: What is the declaration of the variable `playlist`? Why do you have a random number at the end of `Playlist_17967352`? Do you have a `Movie` class?

Comment: I have an array of objects for both playlist and movie

Answer (score 0):

You can just do one split. You know that the first movie id is at `tokens[3]`, so you only need one counter in your loop and then add 3 when indexing `tokens`.

Comment: Not sure I follow, do you mean to split the line into 2?